# Show that $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}:=z$ is irrational with $a,b,c,d,x \in \mathbb{R} ,x$ irrational and $ad\neq bc ,cx+d \neq 0$ and $a,b,c,d$ rational

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that $ad\neq bc $ is sufficient for $z$ irrational because if $ad = bc$ then $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d} = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d} \frac{cb}{ad} = \frac{cax+cb}{cax+da}\frac{b}{d}$ because $cb=da$ nominator and denominator are the same. Hence $\frac{cax+cb}{cax+da}\frac{b}{d} = \frac{b}{d}$ (Contradiction).

But I don't know to prove that $ad \neq bc$  is also necessary for $z$ being irrational.

Comment: $a=\sqrt 2, b=1, c=\sqrt 8, d=1,x=\sqrt 2\implies z=\frac35$ and $ad\ne bc.$

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that $a,b,c,d$ are alll rational

Comment: @RM777: so you can even restrict them to be integers.

Comment: In fact, your argument proves necessity, not sufficiency.  That is, you show that $ad=bc\implies z\in \mathbb Q$. but that isn't what you were asked.

Comment: Yes, the proof is not complete because maybe there could be a z with $ab\neq cd$ which is still rational.

Comment: @YvesDaoust you can pick any rational. I am not sure but maybe you can transform the expression so they are integers in this case you would be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume by contradiction that

$$\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}=\frac pq,$$ or

$$(qa-pc)x+qb-pd=0,$$ and $x$ is rational !

Note that this doesn't work when $qa-pc=qb-pd=0$, which is equivalent to $ad=
bc$.

Comment: Ok I understood why it wouldn't work if $qa-pc=qb-pd=0$ but why is this equivalent to $ad \neq bc$?

Comment: @RM777: sorry, I meant $=$.

Comment: I got it now if $(qa-pc)x+qb-pd=0$ then either $(qa-pc)x = qb-pd$ or $qa-pc=qb-pd=0$ in the first case $ x = \frac{qb-pd}{qa-pc}$ which would be a contradiction to the fact that x is irrational in the second case $qa=pc;qb=pd$ if we would say $ad \neq bc \iff adp \neq bcp \iff aqb \neq bqa $ this is also a contradiction therefore in this case $ad=bp$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {ax+b}{cx + d} =z$

$ax + b = z(cx + d) $

$x(a-cz) = zd - b$.  ($cz$ is irrational and $a$ is rational so $a \ne cz$ and $a -cz \ne 0$.)

$x =\frac {zd- b}{a-cz}$.

If $z$ is rational then so is $x$.  But $x$ isn't so $z$ can't be either.